# How can I get the tags for a headline in a clock report formula?

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to understand how to retrieve the tags for a headline that is being processed by a clock mode report formula. Suppose I have a clock report table defined like this.

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :maxlevel 2 :scope nil :formula "$3='(headline-get-tags $1)::@2$3=string(\"Tags\")"                                                                       
#+END:
```

I can define a simple formula that returns the length of the headline, but I have yet to find an easy way to find the tags associated with the headline.

```
(defun headline-get-tags (headline)
  "Return the tags for a headline"
  (length headline))
```

Is there a simple way to get the tags with a headline?

Comment: I don't think this quite answers your question, but `org-get-tags-string` returns the tags on the current headline (i.e. where `point` is) as a :-seperated string.

Comment: Yes, I had found that function as well, but it's not quite it. I think the problem is a bit more complicated, because I don't think the table formula has full access to the complete headline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clock tables support a `:properties` option:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :properties ("ALLTAGS")
#+END:
```

And it turns out that tags are available by the *special* property name `ALLTAGS`. Here are the others:

http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-properties.html#Special-properties