# org-mode backend: how to find tags of enclosing headline?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, jupyter

I am trying to write on org-mode backend to generate Jupyter Notebook, specifically optimized for producing slides using RISE (see https://github.com/hkarl/org-juslides if interested).

Suppose I have a src-code block. How can I find out the tags of its enclosing headline (if any tags exist)?

The closest thing I found is this [How can I get the tags for a headline in a clock report formula?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8093/how-can-i-get-the-tags-for-a-headline-in-a-clock-report-formula?newreg=e6c2e67f97334c889bbb3b9d627f5a9f), 
 and [Org-mode backend: access properties in heading](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22703/org-mode-backend-access-properties-in-heading) - but they are after somewhat different problems.

I know how to get at attributes of the src-block itself, but I'd rather not have to repeat a "skipslide" tag already set in the headline.

I suppose it would be possible traversing org-element-lineage, but that seems like vast overkill. Is there any simpler option?

Any pointers much appreciated!

```
(defun org-juslides-src-block (src-block contents info)
  (let ( (code (org-export-format-code-default src-block info))
     (animate (org-export-read-attribute :attr_juslides src-block :animate))
     )
    (print "src block")
    (print (org-element-lineage src-block '('heading) ))
    (print animate)
    (org-juslides-cell "code"
               (if animate
               "fragment"
             "-")
               code)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Untested, but maybe `(org-export-get-tags (org-export-get-parent-headline src-block) info '("invalid" "tags") t)`

Comment: Wonderful, right on spot! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Solved by rasmus, with kudos:

```
(org-export-get-tags (org-export-get-parent-headline src-block) info '("invalid" "tags") t)
```

(or, in detail, to also consider the option to use an attribute in the src-block itself):

```
  (let* ( 
     (tags (org-export-get-tags (org-export-get-parent-headline src-block) info '("invalid" "tags") t))
     (skipslide (or (member "skipslide" tags)
            (org-export-read-attribute :attr_juslides src-block :skip)
            ))
     )
```